# Why does inter process shared memory require sudo?

Tags: c++, linux

I am learning the inter process communication via shared memory program and coded a very simple program. It works well except that it requires sudo to function correctly.

If I don't type sudo, there is an error like this

```
"shmat error: Permission denied "
```

for the process that creates the shared memory, and there is an error like this

```
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
```

for the process that tries to read from the share memory. Does anybody know the reason that cause this or this type of program indeed requires root? Thanks.

```
/*
 *This is the process that creates the shared memory
 */
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int shm_id,i;
    key_t key;
    unsigned long *shmap;
    char* name = "/home/veydan/code/cpshm"; // 0 size file
    key = ftok(name,1234);
    if ( key == -1 )
       perror("ftok error");
    shm_id = shmget(key,20480000,IPC_CREAT);
    if( shm_id == -1 ) {
       perror("shmget error");
       return;
    }
    shmap = (unsigned long*)shmat(shm_id,NULL,0);
    if(shmap==-1) {
       perror("shmat error");
       return;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 512; i++ )
       *(shmap+i) = i;

    if ( shmdt(shmap)==-1 )
       perror(" detach error ");
}

/*
 *This is the process that reads from the shared memory
 */
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int shm_id,i;
   key_t key;
   unsigned long *shmap, tmp;
   char* name = "/home/veydan/code/cpshm";
   key = ftok(name,1234);
   if ( key == -1 )
      perror("ftok error");
   shm_id = shmget(key,20480000,IPC_CREAT);    
   if ( shm_id == -1 ) {
      perror("shmget error");
      return;
   }     
   shmap = (unsigned long*)shmat(shm_id,NULL,0);
   for ( i = 0; i < 512; i++ ) {
      tmp = *(shmap+i);
      printf("%lu ", tmp);
      *(shmap+i) = tmp*2;
   }    
   if( shmdt(shmap) == -1 )
      perror(" detach error ");

}
```

Comment: The second argument of `ftok` isn't allowed to be zero.

Comment: Likely the segment you are trying to create already exists and this process doesn't have permission to access it.

Comment: The file associate with this segment (/home/veydan/code/cpshm) is in my own home directory, I suspect I have permission to access it. And it is a zero byte file so it should not conflict with anybody else. Is that correct?

Comment: I set the second argument of ftok to an non zero number, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. The shmget needs to have the right permission (listed in bits/shm.h).

Comment: @VeydanWu instead of editing the question and marking it "solved" in the title, provide an answer to the question and mark that one as [*accepted*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

([Answered in the comments - converted to a community Wiki Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

The OP wrote:

> The `shmget` needs to have the right permission (listed in `bits/shm.h`).